# ecryptfs in centos

Tags: centos, centos-5

I am trying to install ecryptfs on Cent0s 5.5. Thee process is:

```
yum install ecryptfs-utils
```

It seems to run fine.

However when I do

```
modprobe ecryptfs
```

It returns FATAL: Module ecryptfs not found.

Any clue would be helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

See if the file /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/fs/ecryptfs/ecryptfs.ko exists. If it does not, then check the version of the kernel you're running and see if the kernel-`uname -r` package contains the ecryptfs.ko file.

(Where you see uname -r in the text above, replace it with the output of the command).

Answer (score 0):

check this out :   https://plone.lucidsolutions.co.nz/linux/centos/7/install-centos-plus-kernel-kernel-plus/view

you need to use kernel-plus to enable ecryptfs in the kernel

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thanks for your contribution. Providing the link for reference is useful, but you must also [include the essential information](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) in the post. Please **edit your answer** so it contains that information. You might also like to take the [Tour] and read the [Answer] page, to better familiarise yourself with this site.